# HTML: How to make a readonly textarea copyable in iOS-devices

Tags: html, ios, textarea, copy-paste, readonly

How do I make a `textarea` and `input type="text"` **highlightable** and **copyable** on iOS-devices?

This does not work:

```
<textarea readonly="readonly">Totally readonly, cannot be copied</textarea>
```

Neither does:

```
<textarea disabled="disabled">Totally readonly, cannot be copied</textarea>
```

**EDIT**: The text-area is constantly being updated, so a one-off transformation of it won't work.

The content of the textarea can also be HTML.

I have a JSFiddle that I tested this on: http://jsfiddle.net/sebnilsson/jfvWZ/

Comment: You only want to prevent the user from modifying the text while keep it selectable and copyable?

Comment: @Hejazi Yes, that is correct!

Comment: You could place an invisible button over the textView that copies the text, or a button next to it that says "copy".

Comment: @AMayes Without Flash, wouldn't that button do nothing?

Comment: @Seb Nilsson Um, what?  Unless by "flash" you mean "Objective-C", your question is meaningless.

Comment: @AMayes Aha, so they removed Safari from iOS? Maybe all the HTML-jargon and tags in the question confused you...

Comment: Check.  I read "textarea" as "textView".  Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution could be to find all the readonly textareas on the page and render a div with the contents in place of the read only field. I have written some very simple JS to demonstrate this.

Something along the lines of

```
$('textarea[readonly]').removeAttr('readonly').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide().after('<div data-textarea="' + $this.attr('id')
        + '" class="textarea">' + $this.val() + '</div>');
}).on('textareachange', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('[data-textarea="' + $this.attr('id') + '"]').html($this.val());
});
```

You will also need to trigger the event when you update the textarea value. 
For example

```
$('textarea').val('test').trigger('textareachange');
```

There's a more extensive example here with examples on the styling etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssfUx/3/

Comment: This would work, if it wasn't for a constraint in my problem. Updated the question, sorry.

Comment: Seb your edit had a function that wasn't in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I've successfull select some text on my iPhone, but needs many try.

```
<textarea readonly onfocus="this.blur();">Totally readonly, CAN BE copied</textarea>
```

and the last : http://jsfiddle.net/jfvWZ/6/

```
<div>
    <label>Plain div</label><br />
    <div id="plain-div" onFocus="this.blur();">
        Plain div
    </div>
</div>
```

Easy to select the text on iPhone

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle and doesn't work on an iPhone 5 with the latest iOS. http://jsfiddle.net/jfvWZ/ That you can copy from a div was never an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise ran into this issue.

Not sure if the following is a decent, correct or semantic alternative, but it worked for me.

I simply changed the textarea to a div readonly, same styles applied.

The one drawback is that in JavaScript I couldn't target the div with this['myForm']. It doesn't appear to be a child of the form element in DOM.

Instead I had to get the element by id and set it's innerHTML, rather than set the value as with textarea.

It worked on Ipad 1 IOS5 and Iphone 4s IOS7 I am now able to select and copy text to clipboard.